# vbscript copy all rules applied to one PST file to another

Tags: vbscript, outlook

I have two pst files. I want to apply all rules that are applied to first pst file to second pst file. Is it possible to do this with vbscript and without VBA. I think VBA can be run only on Outlook itself not as independent script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have two pst files. I want to apply all rules that are applied to first pst file to second pst file. Is it possible to do this with vbscript and without VBA.

Yes, it's possible to do this with VBScript because VBScript can use the same COM-based Outlook Office Automation API as VBA, except objects are late-bound (so if there are any typing errors in your script you won't know about them until you run it).

To convert VBA to VBScript, you need to do the following:

1. Copy and paste your VBA code into a `*.vbs` file.
2. Remove type information from your variable declarations
3. Optionally, but strongly recommended: add `Option Explicit` on line 1.
4. Change the Office COM automation interop code to use the late-bound `CreateObject` and `GetObject` functions instead of VBA/VB6-specific constructor or COM API calls.

   ```
   ' Change this VBA/VB6:
   Set reminder = New Outlook.Reminder
   ' To this VBS:
   Set reminder = CreateObject("Outlook.Reminder")
   ```

   ```
   ' Change this VBA/VB6:
   Set app = Outlook.Application
   ' To this VBS:
   Set app = GetObject("Outlook.Application")
   ```

So this VBA:

```
Sub Foo()

    Dim foo As String
    foo = ""

    Dim reminder As Outlook.Reminder
    Set reminder = Outlook.Application.Reminders.Item(1)

End Sub
```

...becomes this VBScript:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Foo()

    Dim foo
    foo = ""

    Dim reminder
    Set reminder = GetObject( "Outlook.Application" ).Reminders.Item(1)

End Sub

Call Foo ' Enter into the Foo() subroutine from the top-level script.
```

> I think VBA can be run only on Outlook itself not as independent script.

This is true, however when using VBScript (when run from `cscript`, `wscript` or any other Active Scripting host, like IIS) you're still using the same Office automation API as VBA, so you still need Outlook to be installed on your computer and run the script in a normal desktop session (and not Session 0 or as a headless process). You also need to ensure your script's host has the same ISA ("bitness") as Outlook (i.e. x86 vs x64).

Comment: "not Session 0" means? Shall I schedule the script in Task Scheduler using cscript exe.

Comment: @itsraja Session 0 is a separate "headless" user-session in Windows where Services run. Office COM automation is not supported in headless scenarios such as running inside Session 0 (though it may still work, it just isn't supported by Microsoft - and you'll likely run into some kinds of problems). Scheduled Tasks can be configured to run in Session 0 or in an interactive desktop session - see here: https://serverfault.com/questions/458848/can-i-schedule-a-windows-task-to-run-in-an-interactive-desktop-session